# Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора

Tags: c#, sql, access

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Добавить
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Выберите одну строку!", "Внимание!");
            return;
        }

        //Запомним выбранную строку
        int index = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

        //Проверим данные в таблицы
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value == null ||
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Не все данные введены!", "Внимание!");
            return;
        }

        //Считаем данные
        string Cod = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string Title = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string Index = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string Description = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        string ChemicalClass = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        string Price = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

        //Создаем соеденение
        string connectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database.mdb";//строка соеденения
        OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);//создаем соеденение

        //Выполянем запрос к БД
        dbConnection.Open();//открываем соеденение
        string query = "INSERT INTO [Pigments] VALUES ('" + Cod + "', '" + Title + "','" + Index + "','" + Description + "','" + ChemicalClass + "','" + Price + "')";//строка запроса
        OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection);//команда

        //Выполняем запрос
        if (dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
```

Comment: А если добавляю столбцы то пишет неверный синтаксис к примеру пишу так          string query = "INSERT INTO [Pigments](Title,Index,Description,ChemicalClass,Price) VALUES ('" + Cod + "', '" + Title + "','" + Index + "','" + Description + "','" + ChemicalClass + "','" + Price + "')";

Comment: Как тут надо сформулировать правильно

Comment: price - это число? Зачем оно в кавычках в запросе?

Comment: Точно я только щас понял что я этот запрос оформил как на обновление а не как добавление

Comment: Вы посмотрите какой тип данных имеет каждое поле и форматируйте соответственно типу. В текущем виде - все поля текст (string, varchar), что маловероятно. Не важно, добавление это или обновление.